# I'm bugged in a map and I'm going to lose my best soldier, what can I do to get him out?

Tags: xcom-enemy-within

I just equiped my best soldier (A just now max ranked Sniper) with the skeleton Suite. When I was going to bring him in position with the hook he just got placed out of the map and cannot move anywhere. I thought "Hm, that's ok then I have to finish the mission with out his force" After 2 deaths in my team I got pissed and checked for a savegame because with the snipers firepower things would have gone different. But the last save game Is 6 hours ago.

Well I had just like 1 turn to finish the objective. I did so and the next objective was like "X turns until airstrike! any one who is not in the pick up area until then will be left behind and will die!"

And my sniper is still unable to move anywhere and I would bet just because her is light years away from the air strike wont stop the game mechanic from killing him.

What can I do? I don't want to lose the guy I put my best equip and all exp in to such kind of a bug.

Is there a way I can recover him from dying after the mission?

Or to move him in some other way into the area?

Since the game has cheated me in this situation cheating would be a option for me as well!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have figured out that there is a developer console for the game. I was going to name a Sniper *Ken Levine*, which would activate a so-called superhero sniper, but I later read that this deactivates the Steam achievements, so I didn't try it and thus I can't confirm.

[By activating the developer console](http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/Developer_Console_-_XCOM:EU_2012), it became possible to press `\` to enter various codes, one of which was `TeleportAllToCursor`. (There is a case-sensitive autocomplete feature built in.)

This command made the whole squad teleport to the cursor and I was able to save the sniper.

Comment: And _this_ didn't disable achievements?

Comment: @Lohoris: Nope it didn't! I suggest it is, because the first thing would have been an implemented solution and the second is a patched binary. Ofc it could be checked aswell. But since this mode exist for testing purpose it would be inefficient to disable stuff you could want to test.

Comment: @Lohoris: Well as I used it just to secure my sniper and backed up after that to the original files, I can't say how it is WHILE it is active. but enabling it and improving stuff and returning to the original files will after that not disable achivements at all.